# Turtlebot 2 and arbotix

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, arbotix, groovy-turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a recent convert to Ubuntu and have picked up a Turtlebot 2. I have been able to go through almost all the tutorials with little problems that I have been able to figure out and fix through some ingenuity and google searching. My temporary goal is to try and get my Turtlebot (Atlas) to fetch me beer for the fridge. I will be pairing Atlas with an arm controlled by an Arbotix controller and have been looking into this stage of the project and feel extremely out of my depths.

I was wondering if anyone could give some insight on where to begin to learn python, and how to start the second stage of the project. That being the programming and interfacing of the arm and the ROS software.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55859/turtlebot-2-and-arbotix/) by [chipezy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4250/chipezy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Python.org Tutorials](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) are a great starting point for learning python.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0